# I would like to draw the graph shown in the attached image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overleaf, diagbox

I would like to draw the graph shown in the below image?

[image: this graph]

I tried and reached this graph showing the below image with Latex code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm}


%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

%pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%colours
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-2,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-2)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\draw(0,0)grid(5,5)
\draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
%\draw (1,1) -- (3,3);
%\draw[thick] (1,1) -- (3,3);
%\draw[ultra thick] (1.5,1.5) - - (3.5,1.5);
%\draw[ultra thick][Stealth-Stealth] (1.5,1.5) - - (3.5,1.5);
%\draw[ultra thick][Circle-Stealth] (1.5,1.5) - - (3.5,1.5);
\draw[{Circle[scale=2,open]}-{Stealth[scale=2]}] (1.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) node[midway,above ] {$\mathbf{a}$};

\draw (0.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (0.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (0.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[red] (0.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (0.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (0.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (0.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (0.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (0.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (0.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[red] (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (1.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (1.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (1.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (1.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (1.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (1.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (2.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (2.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (2.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[red] (2.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (2.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (2.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (2.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (2.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (2.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (2.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (3.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (3.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (3.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[red] (3.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (3.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (3.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (3.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (3.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (3.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (3.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw (4.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (4.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (4.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[red] (4.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (4.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (4.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (4.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (4.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw (4.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\fill[lightgray] (4.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\draw  (3.5,3.5) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (4.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) -- (3.5,3.5) ;
\fill[red]  (3.5,3.5) -- (4.5,3.5) -- (4.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) -- (3.5,3.5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: According to my current code, this is my graph]

Comment: Curved lines are not possible using picture.  Everything would be easier using TikZ (or pstricks) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the second image to get you started with TikZ.

[image]

The main ideas:

- Use the TikZ `matrix` library with `matrix of math nodes` to create the grid. Set the height and width of the nodes.
- Set `row sep` and `column sep` to `-\pgflinewidth` so the borders of the nodes overlap.
- In the code below I called the matrix `(space)`. Then the cells can be referenced by their row and column numbers, e.g., `(space-1-2)` is the node in row 1, column 2.
- I made macros `\oo` and `\OO` for the unfilled and filled circles.
- After the matrix is drawn, use ordinary TikZ commands to draw the arrows and labels.
- The rectangle for the Delaunay region is drawn `on background layer` so the grid and circles are visible.
- Use `\tikzset` to define the specialized dash style and line-shaped node for the labels on the right.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}

\tikzset{mydash/.style={line width=.25pt, dash pattern=on 2.5pt off 2.5pt, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=-1.1mm},
    linenode/.style={draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=0mm, label={[align=left]right:{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\oo}{\scalebox{2}{$\circ$}}
\newcommand{\OO}{\scalebox{2}{$\bullet$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
  \matrix (space) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw, semithick, minimum height=15mm, minimum width=10mm, text=blue}]
{\oo &  \oo & \oo \\ 
 \oo & \oo & |[fill=gray!30]|\oo \\ 
 \OO & \oo & \oo \\};
\draw[mydash] (space-1-1.center) --++ (0,1)node(a0){};
\draw[mydash] (space-1-2.center) --++ (0,1)node(b0){};
\draw[mydash] (space-1-1.center) --++ (-.7,0)node(a1){};
\draw[mydash] (space-2-1.center) --++ (-.7,0)node(b1){};
\scoped[on background layer]\draw[fill=gray!30] (space-1-1.center) rectangle (space-2-2.center);
\draw[<->] (a0.center) --node[above]{Spacing[0]} (b0.center);
\draw[<->] (b1.center) --node[sloped, above]{Spacing[1]} (a1.center);
\draw[<-, shorten <=2mm] (space-3-1.center) to[bend right] ++(.5,-1.5) node[below right]{Image Origin};
\draw[<-, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm] (space-3-3.center) to[bend left] ++(1.5,0) node[right=-1mm]{Pixel Coordinates};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=4mm]space-2-3.center) to[bend left]++ (1.5,0)node[linenode=Pixel Coverage\\Voronoi Region]{};
\draw[<-] ([shift={(-2mm,-6mm)}]space-1-2.center) to[bend left]++ (2.7,1)node[linenode=Linear Interpolation Region\\Delaunay Region]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```